# android ICS: database used to save browser passwords?

Tags: android, passwords

In Android ICS, where does the browser app store the username and password. For e.g. if I login to gmail, the browser asks whether the password should be remembered. I know that there is a databases folder under /data/data/com.android.browser/ which stores database for autofill and cookies. Is the password also stored in one of these databases?

Thanks.

Comment: Even if these were publicly accessible, I seriously doubt that the default ICS browser stores the passwords without hashing them first...

Comment: @AlexLockwood I just want to know where the passwords are stored.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have ICS handy to test, but the Jellybean emulator stores website passwords in *plain text* in the file

/data/data/com.android.browser/databases/webview.db

This may however not be representative of what would happen on a device - for one thing, you may get the mobile version of Chrome instead of the traditional android Browser?

There may also be some support for token-based authentication, where an app may not ever actually know the password.

Answer (score 0):

For obvious security reasons, the default Android browser stores its data in a private sandbox/folder where other third party applications cannot access it. Each application has its own cache, cookie store etc. You can read more about Cookie Management [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) (scroll down).

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.  The fact that the file permissions are set such that the linux kernel won't let a different unprivileged userid access the file says nothing about how they are actually stored in the file.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, OK, well do you at least agree that the passwords are probably not publicly accessible to other third party applications? Because that's more what I was getting at lol

Comment: No, because many 3rd party applications run privileged code.  You can ignore rooted devices when declining to add features, but you have to take them into account when talking security.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I agree with you about the rooted devices. I guess we just interpreted the question differently. I was referencing the developer's site and stated that it's not "publicly accessible"... i.e. you can't use the public SDK methods to retrieve it. IMO StackOverflow is not really really a great place to ask questions about how to hack into privileged sandbox environments w/ rooted devices anyway. I mean, I guess it's not all that bad to ask questions like that here... but it's not exactly a "programming question"... and people on Android Enthusiasts might have better answers anyway.

Comment: The question doesn't ask if the file is accessible, it asks which file is used, and cites two examples of database which are not usually accessible.  The question remains unanswered.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, the OP asked "where does the browser app store the username and password." I answered "in its own private sandbox". From a developer's point of view, that's all you need to know. From a hacker's point of view, maybe not... but StackOverflow is not a place to facilitate that sort of behavior anyway.

Comment: I guess I have triggered quite a debate, should I delete the question?

Comment: No... I'm kind of just arguing for the sake of argument anyway lol. I agree with @ChrisStratton 's points too. :)

Comment: My question is just out of curiosity, I wanted to know how and where the android browser stores my password, if I do select the "remember password" option.